# What is a function group (in older literature)?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I am reading Goldberg's 'Invariant transformations, Conservation laws and energy-momentum' from 1980. He frequently uses the notion of a function group.

For example: "For any field theory whose field equations are derivable from an action integral defined over spacetime, invariance of its action with respect to a Lie group leads to a differential conservation law for each parameter of the group whenever the resulting field equations are satisfied. Invariance of its action with respect to a function (?) group leads to a set of differential identities for the field equations themselves --- one for each independent transformation in the group. When the field equations are satisfied, these identities yield conservation laws.".

I am familiar with Lie groups (which he mentions), but when I google `function group' nothing pops up.

Comment: Hard to tell without more context, but it sounds like just a group action (as functions) on a set.

Comment: I added more context. So you mean like representation, but in a form of functions acting on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: OK, that helps, but the author's still being pretty vague.  A representation would be as linear functions on $\mathbb{R}^4$, so I don't think that's what he means.  Since he says *Lie group* first, I am thinking he doesn't intend for this “function group” to be finite or finite-dimensional.  So maybe he's talking about the group of all diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^4$.  The thrust is: to every symmetry corresponds a conserved quantity (Noether's theorem).

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I guess then he speaks of 1-dimensional groups of diffeomorphisms (flows) of vector fields. For example a set of isometries generated by Killing vector fields. Thanks Matthew